# Magento - Stop child products showing in anchor category

Tags: magento, anchor, children

On an anchor category page I'm trying to only show the products directly contained within the category. I don't want to show the products of child categories, it's not appropriate in this case. I really do need to filter the products in my current category, so I need layered navigation, which necessitates an anchor category.

Initially I thought to filter the products in the view.phtml template, but that only filters the products in the view and is not a sensible answer. When I do this I end up with big gaps on my page where child products are present, but simply not displayed. And the product counts (eg. "1-12 of 117 products") are "incorrect".

From what I've read, this is going to require a core rewrite. Probably of an index process. I don't really know where to start with this rewrite, and I'm sure it's going to be rather involved.

Are any of my assumptions wrong? Have you already solved this problem?

Comment: I don't know how I can be clearer. I just want products that are not directly in a category from showing up in the category on the front end. I want the category to remain an anchor category. The code I have written is a dead-end, so there is probably no point in posting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php`

copy to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php`

find function  `addCategoryFilter(` and here you you find code

```
 public function addCategoryFilter(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category)
    {
        $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_id'] = $category->getId();
/*    start to comment here     
if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
            unset($this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor']);
        } else {
            $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor'] = 1;
        }*/
/* new line */

     $this->_productLimitationFilters['category_is_anchor'] = 1;

        if ($this->getStoreId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) {
            $this->_applyZeroStoreProductLimitations();
        } else {
            $this->_applyProductLimitations();
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like it will work! I'm going to give it a go and accept the answer if it works. As this is just a model I will be writing a rewrite module for just that function instead of copying the file to `/app/code/local/mage/`, which I believe is a better way of doing it (although a more complex way to explain in a Stack Overflow answer).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a single line of code if I have understood your condition correct. Magento provides the freedom to enter products in any category regardless of their hierarchy.

So consider the following scenario:

Category A->Category a

Then a product can be assigned to only category a and not to category A. This will work in harmony with the entire magento system including layered navigation and no of prouducts shown on page.

Comment: In this case if you add a product to "Category a" it will be visible in "Category A" if "is anchor" is set to "yes" for "Category A", even if it is not assigned to "Category A". Sorry, this won't work for me.